# ¿Cómo puedo hacer dos llaves foráneas a una sola tabla en Visual Studio EF?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, entity-framework, code-first

```cs
public class Menu
{
    [Key]
    public int idMenu { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(30)]
    public string descripcion { get; set; }
}

 public class DetalleMenu
 {
    [Key]
    public int idDetalleMenu { get; set; }
    public int MenuID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("MenuID")]
    public Menu idMenu { get; set; }

    public int MenuDetalleID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("MenuDetalleID")]
    public Menu idMenuDetalle { get; set; }
}
```

```
Applying automatic migration: 201910270828577_AutomaticMigration.
Precaución: al cambiar cualquier parte del nombre de un objeto pueden dejar de ser scripts válidos y procedimientos almacenados.
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Se especificaron varias columnas de identidad para la tabla 'DetalleMenus'. Sólo se permite una por tabla.
   en System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   en System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   en System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   en System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
   en System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteNonQueryTds(String methodName, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite)
   en System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry)
   en System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   en System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.<NonQuery>b__0(DbCommand t, DbCommandInterceptionContext`1 c)
   en System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch[TTarget,TInterceptionContext,TResult](TTarget target, Func`3 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext, Action`3 executing, Action`3 executed)
   en System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.NonQuery(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
   en System.Data.Entity.Internal.InterceptableDbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   en System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteSql(MigrationStatement migrationStatement, DbConnection connection, DbTransaction transaction, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
   en System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorLoggingDecorator.ExecuteSql(MigrationStatement migrationStatement, DbConnection connection, DbTransaction transaction, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
   en System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteStatementsInternal(IEnumerable`1 migrationStatements, DbConnection connection, DbTransaction transaction, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
   en System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteStatementsWithinTransaction(IEnumerable`1 migrationStatements, DbTransaction transaction, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
   en System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteStatementsWithinNewTransaction(IEnumerable`1 migrationStatements, DbConnection connection, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
   en System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteStatementsInternal(IEnumerable`1 migrationStatements, DbConnection connection, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
   en System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteStatementsInternal(IEnumerable`1 migrationStatements, DbConnection connection)
   en System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.<>c__DisplayClass32.<ExecuteStatements>b__30()
   en System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.<>c__DisplayClass1.<Execute>b__0()
   en System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1 operation)
   en System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute(Action operation)
   en System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteStatements(IEnumerable`1 migrationStatements, DbTransaction existingTransaction)
   en System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteStatements(IEnumerable`1 migrationStatements)
   en System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorBase.ExecuteStatements(IEnumerable`1 migrationStatements)
   en System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteOperations(String migrationId, VersionedModel targetModel, IEnumerable`1 operations, IEnumerable`1 systemOperations, Boolean downgrading, Boolean auto)
   en System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.AutoMigrate(String migrationId, VersionedModel sourceModel, VersionedModel targetModel, Boolean downgrading)
   en System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorLoggingDecorator.AutoMigrate(String migrationId, VersionedModel sourceModel, VersionedModel targetModel, Boolean downgrading)
   en System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Upgrade(IEnumerable`1 pendingMigrations, String targetMigrationId, String lastMigrationId)
   en System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorLoggingDecorator.Upgrade(IEnumerable`1 pendingMigrations, String targetMigrationId, String lastMigrationId)
   en System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.UpdateInternal(String targetMigration)
   en System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.<>c__DisplayClasse.<Update>b__d()
   en System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.EnsureDatabaseExists(Action mustSucceedToKeepDatabase)
   en System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorBase.EnsureDatabaseExists(Action mustSucceedToKeepDatabase)
   en System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Update(String targetMigration)
   en System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorBase.Update(String targetMigration)
   en System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.UpdateRunner.RunCore()
   en System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.BaseRunner.Run()
ClientConnectionId:2c6e4ce5-bd9e-45a7-9a75-d02b030dd5af
Error Number:2744,State:2,Class:16
```

**Se especificaron varias columnas de identidad para la tabla 'DetalleMenus'. Sólo se permite una por tabla.**

Comment: Por favor, comparta la migración generada para esto.

Comment: Tu intención es crear una relación de uno a muchos entre Menu y DetalleMenu? una llave foránea apunta a menú, pero la otra apunta a la misma tabla  [ForeignKey("MenuDetalleID")], es decir DetalleMenu tiene una llave foránea que apunta a DetalleMenu ese puede ser el error.